# How to display the returned ajax Json results in HTML (using typescript)

Tags: html, ajax, json, typescript

The client (typescript) gets different results from the server, all are in json format.  Sometimes a simple json result, sometimes complex nested jsons.

I need to present the results in a (very) simple html table.

```
function run(): void {
var url = this.selectedKnockoutDropList(); 

$.ajax(url, "GET").done(data => {
    console.log(data);

    *** here I want to do something like : 
        - open/embedd results.html
        - fill a table with the json results parsed somehow
});
```

I tried $('#...).html(data) with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin and Robert - thanks for the quick replies. I took your advises and came with the following generic solution (which can display html text returned from the server or nested json object in a table) :

HTML:

```
    <!--HTML-->        
    <div data-bind="visible: isHtml, html: htmlView"></div>

    <!--SIMPLE JSON-->
    <div data-bind="visible: isJson">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr data-bind="foreach: columns"> 
                    <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
                <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
                    <td data-bind="text: $parent[$data]"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
function run(): void {
this.isHtml(false);
this.isJson(false);

$.ajax(url, "GET").done(data => {
    var jsonObj = data;

    if (typeof (data) === "string") {
        this.htmlView(data);
        this.isHtml(true);
        return;
    }

    if (data instanceof Array === false) {
        jsonObj = [data];
    }

    this.columns([]);
    this.rows([]);

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {

        var item = jsonObj[i];
        var newItem = {};        

        for (var key in item) {
            if (i === 0)
                this.columns.push(key);

            if (typeof item[key] !== "object") {
                newItem[key] = item[key];
            } else {
                for (var deeperKey in item[key]) {
                    this.columns.push(deeperKey);
                    newItem[deeperKey] = item[key][deeperKey];
                }
            }
        }
        this.rows.push(newItem);
    }
    this.isJson(true);
});
```

I used another stackoverflow post (which I can't find right now) for the nested rows.  Obviously flatting the sub-rows is not what I want but it can easily be changed.

It's my first typescript/html program :)

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the JSON into meaningful HTML. This can be done in typescript, javascript. It can be done with jQuery it can be done using javascript templates such a handlebars. It can be done with SPA frameworks like Angular.

Please post an a sample of the returned JSON and I can update with a TypeScript example not using any toolsets or libs.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is an object. To output it to the document you need to first convert it to a string:

```
$.ajax(url, "GET").done(data => {
  $('#...).html(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

However, if you know what kind of data you are getting back and want to output just parts of it, you'll need to loop the JSON. For example, if you had a JSON object like:

```
[
   {name: "Joe", age: 32},
   {name: "Suzy", age 23},
   {name: "Tom", age 28}
]
```

You could output the names like this:

```
$.ajax(url, "GET").done(data => {
   data.forEach(function(person) {
      $(ul).append('<li>' + person.name + '</li>');
   });
}
```